# Facebook access user info if they are not logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Ok, so what I am trying to do is a bit odd, so I can't find anything that gives me even a remote idea about how to do this.

I need to access my personal profile posts:

```
FB.api("/" + myPersonalUserId + "/feed", {limit: 5}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    // do stuff with my user info
});
```

in order to display them on my personal webite, similar to a dynamic blog. But I want it to automatically retrieve these posts without my having to be signed in on each computer that wants to view my site.

Before you get sidetracked on the init, I am using an app and app id that my personal user account has verified access to all permissions.

I know it will require the use of an access token, but how do I get a valid access token without being logged into that computer?

Honestly, I'm starting to question if it is even possible, but if anyone knows how I could accomplish this, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to just cache the data in your own database and refresh it whenver the user uses your App again.

If that´s not good enough, you have to generate and store an Extended User Token. How to create one is explained in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Extended User Tokens are valid for 60 days, there is no User Token that is valid forever. And you should never use Tokens directly on the client, because some user could just copy it from the source. Tokens are meant to be secret, so use it on the server only. You don´t need to use the PHP SDK, a simple CURL call to the Graph API will do it:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[your-app-scoped-id]/feed?access_token=[extended-user-token]
```

Comment: Awesome, I was really trying to avoid the PHP SDK, so this helps a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a solution similar to the one above, but offers a permanent access token.

first, build a url:

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/' + {app user Id, not public Id} + '/feed';
url += '?access_token=' + {app Id} + '|' + {app secret};
url += '&fields=id,name,message,full_picture,created_time'; // these scopes should be approved by corresponding user
url += '&limit=5';
```

then run it by calling a simple ajax request. These variables should be served from the server through ajax, not hardcoded on the client